# Como puedo mostrar los días del mes actual en java?

Tags: java, primefaces, date

tengo la siguiente tabla

```html
<p:dataTable var="detalle" styleClass="columns" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;">

  <p:column headerText="FECHA" style="width:150px;">
    <h:outputText  />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="ENTRADA" style="width:150px;">
    <h:outputText  />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="SALIDA" style="width:150px;">
    <h:outputText  />
  </p:column>


  <p:column headerText="ACCIONES" style="width:120px;text-align: center">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" title="View" onclick="PF('modalIntentos').show();">

    </p:commandButton>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

y en el campo de fecha, quiero que aparezca todos los dias del mes actual
de esta manera por fila
20/02/2018,
21/02/2018
y asi hasta el día ultimo de cada mes, y si cambia de mes, pues también los dias
como puedo hacerlo?
hay alguna funcion de java 8 que me pueda ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Usa el metodo **Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)**, donde **Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH** es una constante del mismo Calendar.

Ej:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 System.out.println(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
 Date marzo = new Date(2018, 2, 1);
 calendar.setTime(marzo);
 System.out.println(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Reusas el objeto Calendar pasandole un nuevo objeto Date con el mes que necesitas con el metodo setTime(), es este caso le paso el siguiente mes que es Marzo

```
Date marzo = new Date(2018, 2, 1);
calendar.setTime(marzo);
```

De esta forma obtiendo el maximo de dias ya solo tienes que aplicar un for desde el dia actual(ó inicial=1 si es el siguiente mes) hasta el dia maximo del mes:

21/02/2018
...
28/02/2018